# Limit scope of node properties to current node only in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm defining a command to draw a red box with nice rounded corners around text or graphics elements in LaTeX with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

  % command to draw a box around something
  \newcommand{\boxed}[1]{
    \tikz 
    \node (boxedword) [draw, rectangle, red, thick, rounded corners=10mm] {#1};%
  }
    
  Normal rectangle:
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [rectangle, draw, minimum size=4.0cm] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
  Boxed rectangle:
  \boxed{
    % same rectangle as above
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [rectangle, draw, minimum size=4.0cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the properties I set for the node (rounded corners and color) are propagated to all subnodes, which is not what I want: of course, the text or graphics within the box should be unchanged. How do I fix that?

[image]

Desired output: black rectangle with sharp corners inside red rectangle with rounded corners.

Comment: First, you should avoid nesting tikzpictures. Wrong and unpredictable things may happen. There are other ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: What would you suggest? I am looking for a command that draws a box around text or plots. These plots may also be drawn with tikz, so unless I define two different commands for that, it may happen that I end up with nested tikzpictures.